# How to protect the process from writeprocessmemory?

Tags: c++, memory

Which function is called in the current process when calling WriteProcessMemory from another process?

Comment: The definition of this question doesn't match its declaration.

Answer (score 5):

No processing of `WriteProcessMemory` in the current process. It happens inside the OS - it maps the foreign process into the address space of the current process, writes to the memory, and unmaps the memory again.

If you need to protect against this, you will have to block all processes from using WriteProcessMemory (or at least, intercept it and check if your process is targetted). This will probably prevent debuggers from working on that system, if you are not careful. This may upset people, and someone that knows what they are doing can probably bypass it.

Comment: And VirtualProtectEx, CreateRemoteThread also nothing not cause in the current process?

Comment: Correct, they all happen inside the OS - the CreateRemoteThread obviously causes another thread to run within the original process, and that can probably be detected if your code know how many threads it "should have" (by enumerating all threads in the process - but it does assume you know that the graphics driver, audio driver, physics engine, etc, etc doesn't create arbitrary threads [on certain hardware, etc]. VirtualProtect and it's siblings is completely part of the OS, so you can't see that from the "target" process.

Comment: To add a little bit here: in a typical case, the target process will be suspended when `WriteProcessMemory` is happening. As such, it typically can't react at all.